# View stuck behind VideoView

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am having an issue trying to hide and show buttons on top of a VideoView.  For simplicity I have an xml file that looks like this, the real one just has a lot more buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoEnter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically when I play a video I set the button to `View.INVISIBLE` and when the video finishes in `onCompletion` I set the button to `View.Visible`.  The issue is the button is clickable but it is behind the VideoView and is not visible. I have been able to make this work in FrameLayout however I need to stretch the videoview to fit the screen which I can only seem to make work in RelativeLayout.  Is there anyway to make all this work in RelativeLayout?

I also tried `.bringToFront()` with no success.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What happens if you declare the Button first?

Comment: Just tried switching them around, the only thing that changed is the button is covered by the VideoView right at the start instead of initially being on top of the VideoView.  I can still click the button, it's just not visible.

Comment: With the FrameLayout solution you had earlier, have you tried wrapping the FrameLayout inside a RelativeLayout (that stretches to fit the screen) and matching the parent? Also have you tried removing the VideoView and Buttons and inflating them back again? And...have you tried using View.GONE for the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fell that this is because you used fill_parent for the VideoView. ALso you have used all the following to be true:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

So, the activity is stretching the whole screen. Do something like this:
Use Linear layout and assign weights to your views.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<VideoView
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:id="@+id/videoEnter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<Button
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried this and it shows the button on bottom and the VideoView on the rest of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need the button to overlay the videoview.  This has the button below the videoview, when it is set to invisible there is background visible as opposed to the video. The videoview needs to stretch to fit the entire screen.

Comment: Ok, your first statement about all my alignments being set to true got me thinking.  I went ahead and removed the left and right alignment statements and it is working now as expected.  Not entirely sure why, but it works so I am not gonna question that:)  I will go ahead and mark this as correct.  Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thats great. I am glad that helped to give you some hint Jacob. I am also curious to know the answer to your new question. :)